# Understanding Keras model architecture (tensor index)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

This script defining a dummy using the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#the-concept-of-layer-node)

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import keras

inputs = Input(shape=(100,), name='A_input')
x = Dense(20, activation='relu', name='B_dense')(inputs)
shared_l = Dense(20, activation='relu', name='C_dense_shared')
x = keras.layers.concatenate([shared_l(x), shared_l(x)], name='D_concat')

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
print(model.summary())
```

yields the following output

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
A_input (InputLayer)             (None, 100)           0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
B_dense (Dense)                  (None, 20)            2020        A_input[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
C_dense_shared (Dense)           (None, 20)            420         B_dense[0][0]                    
                                                                   B_dense[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
D_concat (Concatenate)           (None, 40)            0           C_dense_shared[0][0]             
                                                                   C_dense_shared[1][0]             
====================================================================================================
```

My question concerns the content of the `Connected to` column.
I understand that [a layer can have multiple nodes](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#the-concept-of-layer-node).

In this case `C_dense_shared` has two nodes, and `D_concat` is connected to both of them (`C_dense_shared[0][0]` and `C_dense_shared[1][0]`). So the first index (the `node_index`) is clear to me. But what does the second index mean? From the [source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/9dca90e7053b33f605b6ddb048f1b4fbc145b3f0/keras/utils/layer_utils.py#L94) I read that this is the `tensor_index`:

```
layer_name[node_index][tensor_index]
```

But what does the `tensor_index` mean? And in what situations can it have a value different from `0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [docstring](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py#L85-L91) of the `Node` class makes it quite clear:

```
    tensor_indices: a list of integers,
        the same length as `inbound_layers`.
        `tensor_indices[i]` is the index of `input_tensors[i]` within the
        output of the inbound layer
        (necessary since each inbound layer might
        have multiple tensor outputs, with each one being
        independently manipulable).
```

`tensor_index` will be nonzero if a layer has multiple output tensors. It's different from the situation of multiple "datastreams" (e.g. layer sharing), where layers have multiple *outbound nodes*. For example, `LSTM` layer will return 3 tensors if given `return_state=True`:

1. Hidden state of the last time step, or all hidden states if `return_sequences=True`
2. Hidden state of the last time step
3. Memory cell of the last time step

As another example, feature transformation can be implemented as a `Lambda` layer:

```
def generate_powers(x):
    return [x, K.sqrt(x), K.square(x)]

model_input = Input(shape=(10,))
powers = Lambda(generate_powers)(model_input)
x = Concatenate()(powers)
x = Dense(10, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(model_input, x)
```

From `model.summary()`, you can see that `concatenate_5` is connected to `lambda_7[0][0]`, `lambda_7[0][1]` and `lambda_7[0][2]`:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_7 (InputLayer)             (None, 10)            0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_7 (Lambda)                [(None, 10), (None, 1 0           input_7[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_5 (Concatenate)      (None, 30)            0           lambda_7[0][0]                   
                                                                   lambda_7[0][1]                   
                                                                   lambda_7[0][2]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)                  (None, 10)            310         concatenate_5[0][0]              
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)                  (None, 1)             11          dense_8[0][0]                    
====================================================================================================
Total params: 321 
Trainable params: 321 
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes sense. I did not use `Lambda` or LSTM yet. I will award the bounty to you in 14 hours, since it is not possible to do this earlier.